# Retrieve Image from database for face recognition using c#

Tags: c#, image-processing, emgucv, face-detection, face-recognition

Currently, I am trying to get my faces from the database to used it for face recognition. But now the problem I am facing is, any image it detects also its showing my name.

This is my `C#` code:

```
 while (reader.Read())
 {
    labels.Add(reader.GetValue(0).ToString());
    trainingImages.Add(gray);
 }
```

This is my `EmguCV` image conversion code:

```
currentFrame = grabber.QueryFrame().Resize(320, 240, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.INTER.CV_INTER_CUBIC); //dont disturb this part

    //Convert it to Grayscale
    gray = currentFrame.Convert<Gray, Byte>();

    //Face Detector
    MCvAvgComp[][] facesDetected = gray.DetectHaarCascade(
    face,
    1.2,
    10,
    Emgu.CV.CvEnum.HAAR_DETECTION_TYPE.DO_CANNY_PRUNING,
    new Size(25, 25));
```

It sounds like problem is at the `trainingImages.Add(gray)` just that I don't know how to get it from the database. At the same time, once the face is detected then my whole program becomes too slow.

Can someone help me on this?